# Getting 2 monitors to work off a Lenovo Docking station Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, lenovo

I'm running a new Lenovo x270 laptop with a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 install.  I'm trying to get 2 monitors to work while the laptop is docked in a Lenovo Docking station.  I currently have 1 monitor connected via DisplayPort and 1 monitor connected via DVI (using DVI-HDMI cable).  The Displayport monitor comes up fine and is labeled #2 under Displays.  The DVI monitor is not coming up.

If I unplug the Displayport monitor, the DVI monitor works fine.  For some reason I can't get Ubuntu to use both at the same time.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. did you solve  it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely your video hardware can drive only 1 monitor at a time.  You plug in 2, but it only uses the more preferred type. Usually, unless you have special video hardware (Nvidia quadro, for example), your system supports one external monitor.  We have lots of Dell laptops with VGA, HDMI, and mini Display ports, but only one works at a given time.

If you think that's wrong, write back to tell us what kind of graphics devices you have and what models. Can you show us output from

```
lspci
```

For comparison, here are my video lines

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
```

The Nvidia quadro does allow me to use both devices at onces for 2 monitors, but most of the laptops around here do not allow it.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow.  I know it's Intel but I'm not positive of the model number.

I can flip the lid of the laptop and run 2 screens that way.  The actual laptop screen and the monitor.  

I also have the Lenovo  model prior to this at work running Windows 10 and have no issues running dual monitors almost the same way.  One monitor is connected via DisplayPort the other is VGA.